# Prove small-oh with big-oh

Tags: algorithm, big-o

If I have already known `f(n)` is `O(g(n))`. From the definition of little-oh, how to prove that `f(n)` is `o(n * g(n))`?

Comment: This question might be better suited for [Computer Science Stack Exchange](http://cs.stackexchange.com/), rather than SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Given**: `f(n) is in O(g(n))`.

Using the definition of big-O notation, we can write this as:

```
f(n) is in O(g(n))

=> |f(n)| ≤ k*|g(n)|, for some constant k>0                 (+)
                      for n sufficiently large (say, n>N)
```

For the definition of big-O used as above, see e.g.

- https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/asymptotic-notation/a/big-o-notation

**Prove**: Given `(+)`, then `f(n) is in o(n*g(n))`.

---

Lets first state what little-o notation means:

> Formally, `f(n) = o(g(n))` (or `f(n) ∈ o(g(n))`) as `n → ∞` means that
>   for every positive constant `ε` there exists a constant `N` such that
>
> ```
> |f(n)| ≤ ε*|g(n)|, for all n > N                          (++)
> ```

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation.

Now, using `(+)`, we can write

```
|f(n)| ≤ k*|g(n)|, som k>0, n sufficiently large 

    <=> { n > 0 } <=> n*|f(n)| ≤ k*n*|g(n)|
                  <=> n*|f(n)| ≤ k*|n*g(n)|
                  <=>   |f(n)| ≤ (k/n)*|n*g(n)|            (+++)
```

Return to the definition of little-o, specifically `(++)`, and let, without loss of generality, `k` be fixed. Now, every positive constant `ε` can be described as

```
ε = k/C, for some constant C>0 (with k fixed, k>0)         (*)
```

Now, assume, without loss of generality, that `n` is larger than this `C`, i.e., `n>C`. Then, `(*)` and `(+++)` yields

```
|f(n)| ≤ (k/n)*|n*g(n)| < (k/C)*|n*g(n)| = ε*|n*g(n)|      (**)
                        ^                ^
                        |                |
                    since `n>C`         (*)
```

Since we're studying asymptotic behaviour, we can choose to to assign a lower bound to `n` to any value larger than `C` (in fact, that's in the definition of both big-O and little-o, *"n sufficiently large"*), and hence---by the definition of little-oh above---, we have:

```
- As shown above, (+) implies (**) 
- By the definition of little-o, (**) shows that f(n) is in o(n*g(n))
- Subsequently, we've shown that, given (+), then: f(n) is in o(n*g(n))
```

---

**Result**: If `f(n) is in O(g(n))`, then `f(n) is in o(n*g(n))`, where these two relations refer big-O and litte-O asymptotic bounds, respectively.

---

**Comment**: The result is, in fact, quite trivial. The big-O and little-o notation differ only in one of the two constants used in proving the upper bounds, i.e., we can write the definitions of big-O and little-O as:

- `f(n)` is said to be in `O(g(n))` if we can find a set of positive constants `(k, N)`, such that `f(n) < k*g(n)` holds for all `n>N`.
- `f(n)` is said to be in `o(g(n))` if we can find a positive constant `N`, such that `f(n) < ε*g(n)` holds for all `n>N`, and *for every positive constant* `ε`.

The latter is obvious a stricter constraint, but if we can make use of one extra power of `n` in the left-hand-side of `f(n) < ε*g(n)` (i.e., `f(n) < ε*n*g(n)`), then even for infinitesimal values of `ε`, we can always choose the other constant `N` freely to be sufficiently large for `ε*n` to provide us any constant `k` that can be used to show that `f(n)` is in `O(g(n))` (as, recall, `n>N`).